# Can Android devices access an iOS file system via USB-OTG?

Tags: usb, ios, usb-on-the-go

Using an OTG cable, Stickmount, and Root Explorer, I can view files on my USB flash drives with my Android device.

On Windows, it's possible to view an iOS device's filesystem using programs such as iFunBox or iExplorer.

When I plug my iPhone to my Android device using an OTG cable, it's recognised as a camera instead of a mass storage device.

Is there a way to view an iOS device's filesystem using an Android device and an OTG cable?

Comment: Mass-Storage-Mode is definitely **not** possible as iOS devices don't offer it to begin with (edited your title to ask more generic). Apple iOS devices use a network-like filesystem over USB. You need to install iTunes to see it on Windows. However, I don't know of any current solutions for Android but it's at least not impossible (technically, there is an implementation for Linux available at [libimobiledevice.org](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) which could run on Android but would most  probably require root).

Comment: The kernel can be modified to include a filesystem driver module that can understand Apple's HFS+ filesystem.

Comment: @t0mm13b You could, but that would only help if iOS devices give you direct access to the filesystem over USB. As ce4 said, they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as mentioned in the above comment it's not possible.

In android only some part of Linux is used on the architecture whereas in iOS the complete os is built on it.

Android is hard coded in Java whereas in IOS you will find most of the file in XML format so as the format is different you will end up with an unrecognised file on your Android Device

Comment: As per the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS#Kernel) iOS uses [XNU kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) and not Linux kernel.