# Using MyWi USB 3G Tethering from iPhone to Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Tags: usb-tethering

I've been using MyWi on my jailbroken iPhone 4 for over a year now and it works great giving me a 3G connection to my laptop anywhere I am via the USB tether.

Is this possible to do on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 tablet the same as I can on my laptop?  When I enable MyWi and plug the USB into the Galaxy Tab, nothing happens where I would expect it to pick up on the 3G connection my iPhone has just like my laptop does...

Has anyone got this to work?  The tablet is not rooted and is not part of any Verizon or AT&T plan, no SIM in the tablet...

Anything would help!

Thank you,
-Derek.

Comment: Why not just use the wireless tether option? The Galaxy Tab most likely does not have drivers for the iPhone.

Comment: Bluetooth is another option by the way!. PS: Wifi tether is a battery hog and if you commute via train you might have plugged in the USB anyway.

Comment: My experience is bluetooth tethering is just as bad, but slower speeds.

Comment: What would be my wireless tether options? I am trying to use my 3G connection from my iPhone via MyWi jailbreak app so I have a free 3G connection to the tablet using my 3G unlimited data plan...

Comment: Per MyWi's website: "Create iPad or iPhone WiFi Hotspot to connect mutiple laptops or mobile devices to share your iPhone/iPad's internet connection" You should be able to create a wifi hotspot with your iPhone that your Galaxy Tab 2 can connect to or possibly create a bluetooth connection from your phone to your tablet for connection sharing.

Comment: thank you...and yes, I have done that. but the key point here is that I want to use my iPhone's 3G connection, not WiFi.  Using MyWi currently I simply turn on USB tethering when I am on 3G and plug the USB into my laptop...I then have 3G internet access on my laptop when there is not a WiFi connection available.  I'd like to do this on my Galaxy 2 Tab....not sure if it is possible.

Comment: You can't share your 3G connection over USB but you can over wifi. Just as you just turn on usb tethering, you can turn on Wifi hotspot to share your 3G connection via making your iPhone a hotspot. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zoIsmVYuTo

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you can't share your iPhone's 3G connection with your Galaxy Tab 2 over USB.

Comment: And what is the long one? I.e. we would like to know what are the facts and sources that you rely on to give that short answer

Comment: USB tethering would require the Galaxy Tab 2 to have a driver for the iPhone, which it does not. In theory a person could write a driver for the android operating system to utilize USB OTG for the iPhone, but as far as I can tell one does not exist. This post (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/can-android-devices-access-an-ios-file-system-via-usb-otg) references the limitation of connecting to an iPhone, but any sort of remote possibility would require root at the very least along with lots of development work.